# How do I make explorer unzip zip files to a folder when I double-click them?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, zip

When I download a zipped folder and double-click on it in Explorer it treats it like a normal folder and takes me into it.

Is there a way to change this behaviour so that when I double-click foo.zip it will extract the contents into .\foo\?

Comment: Extract all seems to result in the contents of the folder being extracted into the directory the zip file is in. I usuallly use 7z which has "extract to \foo\…" as a right-click option